# autosize excel 2010 comment box when add a lot of text

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, comments

I'm finding some way to make Excel comment box auto-size when I add a lot of text into it.
Some tries with Google and I've got this from [Ozgrid](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=14889) but it doesn't work on my Excel 2010. Please help me some idea to make it work! Thanks!

```
Sub robot_comment() 

    ' robot_comment Macro 
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+R 

    Dim objComment As Comment 

    Set objComment = ActiveCell.AddComment 
    With objComment 
        .Visible = False 
        .Text Text:="robot" 
        .Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True 
    End With 
End Sub
```

Comment: It works for me.  What specific problem are you having?

Comment: For me, it doesn't work at all!

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean in your case? Do the comments get created at all?

Comment: yes, when I hit `Ctrl + Shift + R` the comment was not gotten created at all.

Comment: Just to check: you did specify the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Shift+R to call this macro? Because it's not sufficient to paste this code in the editor - the shortcut needs to be set in another menu.

Answer (score 2):

Keyboard shortcuts must be defined in the macro creation screen, not in the macro comments.